# RTSP IP Local Streaming with Jw-player For Android

Tags: android, streaming, localhost, jwplayer, rtsp

I have a little Android server which I want to use only for Show the stream of my local cameras on chrome. I have a Json file with all my local cameras streaming, and for each stream I want a player.
I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var uu='json/camaras.json';
      $.get(uu,function(data){
        var longi = data['camera'].length;
        var i=0;
        for(i=0;i<longi;i++){
          var stream = data['camera'][i]['stream'];
          jwplayer('myElement').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
            'file': 'camera.stream',
            'streamer': stream,
            'autostart': 'true',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'stretching': 'exactfit',
            'width': '640',
            'height': '352'
          });

        }
      });
    </script>
```

But my console log shows me this **No suitable players found and fallback enabled** 
Seems that I'm not configuring it on the right way. Does anyone knows how it actually works? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have an example link of where you are running this?

Comment: I'm running it on my localhost. I don't have any link. But if you need more code, just let me know.

Comment: Well, RTSP is not something that is supported by either Flash or HTML5.

Comment: I have seen on forums that rstp it's actually supported by jwplayer. The problem here is that when I put an rstp link like this: **rtsp://stream.ilight.net:1935/apa/live1'** it shows me the players but when I put a rstp stream with an ip adress instead of like this **rtsp://[Ip address]:80/live** sends me a console error of **Object has no setup method**

Comment: There is no way. Where in the forums did you read that? We only mention using it outside of the player set up for Android. It is not supported in the actual JW Player set up.